# Need advice on building a diagonal keyboard for Iphone App

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, keyboard, ios-keyboard-extension

I want to make an IPhone App, but sort of a strange one. I want to make an app where the keyboard is on the bottom left corner of the screen. I don't have any experience with ios development but I have coding experience and web-dev experience. Would I have to build the keyboard from scratch with objective-c or UI kit or could I use Swift UI? Are there any libraries you could recommend to help me build this?

I know for instance that The New York Times mini-crossword has what appears to be an in-house keyboard https://nytco-assets.nytimes.com/m/ipad_ads_portrait_10_mini_puzzle-2.png

Here is sort of what I want it to look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4M4R.jpg

Comment: There are many, many ways to approach this, but which approach depends on a lot of other factors related to your app structure and design. *"I don't have any experience with iOS development..."* -- well, the first thing you need to do is get some experience with iOS development. There is really no way to offer you any sort of help at this point - we could give you 5 different approaches, but nothing would make sense until you have some experience, and none of those 5 may end up being the correct / best approach.

Comment: DonMag thank you for the reply. I have some books on iOS development that I am looking forward to use as references during the process. I am experienced in ReactJS  (component based software dev). I want a super nice keyboard but it is diagonal and In the corner. I think that if you gave me an approach I could try to learn the patterns and APIs that you describe and learn iOS by following your approach. If it is not the best approach, Its fine by me because I see it as a learning experience. Would it be helpful to say that the general app idea is a diagonal messaging App?

Comment: Couple things to investigate to get you started: use stack views inside a "parent" view to create a "grid" of buttons, then use `CGAffineTransform` to rotate and position the parent view... use `CATextLayer` and `CAShapeLayer` with bezier paths to "draw" the angled keyboard, and then use  `path.contains(touchPoint)` to detect which "key" was tapped.